# Pagination with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I've build an application (with PHP, Codeigniter and jQuery) that uses ajax for pagination, similar to how Twitter made it back in the day (clicking a button to load in more data).

It's all quite well, but there are a few issues however.

When there are no more posts left to load in, I want the "load-more"-button to be removed. However, right now I can only check if there are any posts left when I click the button, and the script returns null.

This is how it is now: Let's say that there are 14 posts in the database. 5 is loaded per default.

**1** - click load-more, 5 more posts are loaded. 4 remain.

**2** - click load-more, the remaining 4 posts are loaded.

**3** - click load-more, no more remaining posts, button disappears

But I want to get rid of step 3, the application should "be aware" of that there are no more posts left to render at step 2.

I am sure there are a simple way that I haven't thought if yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple. select 6 posts instead of 5 and display only 5.If no of posts less than 6 dont display more button.

```
if ($num_rows < 6){
  //remove more button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global Javascript variable holding the amount of total posts something like this:

```
var total = <?php echo $total ?>;
```

And after the call compare the amount to the total:

```
if($('.post').length == total) // .post being database results
    $('#loadmore').hide();
```

Comment: True, but then there are som other issues. Like what happens if the user posts another post. Then the true total number of posts would be $total+1

Comment: Well, if someone posts another post this would be handled through jQuery as well right? Because it will be AJAX submitted and added to the list. Since `total` is a Javascript variable, you can simply do `total++` in the same code that you add the post to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Return a JSON object with one property that is an array (the entries) and one property that is a bool "EOF" or such to indicate when there is no more entries to load.

if(response.EOF)
//Hide button..

Ohh and add the id of the last post from current pagination in the AjaxRequest.
That way the server gives you say 25 posts from the last one it gave you.
Then you dont get offsets if a new post is added during pagination.

Answer (score -1):

you could try something like this

```
if ($num_rows < 5){
/*what ever you want removed */
}
```

at the end of you loop

Answer (score -1):

## Please, please, please - do not do pagination in Ajax!

It is pain in the a$$ to navigate such pages natural way, unable to use back button or reload button or set a bokmark or anything!

not to mention clients that doesn't support js at all

Comment: you can use jquery address plugin for that purpose.

Comment: If done correctly all of the things you mention will work just fine.